# HttpWebRequest No Response when calling an external website API

Tags: c#, api, httpwebrequest, uri, httpwebresponse

I am trying to use [an API that helps detect bad IP](https://ipwarner.com/documentation), with C# code.

Here is the documentation.

> ### How to call the API?
>
> API requests are sent in a specific form. The API key is sent directly to the URL, as is the IP address from which you want to retrieve the information. This is the form of the URL called.
>
> https://api.ipwarner.com/API-KEY/IP

According to this, I wrote a function:

```cs
private static string Get(string uri)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream ?? throw new InvalidOperationException());
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

And called it with:

```cs
string myresult = Get("https://api.ipwarner.com/myapikey/myip");
```

However, it got stuck at `HttpWebResponse`. There was no response at all.

(I confirm my API key is available and the input IP is right)

How's that wrong?

Comment: Try to catch an error. So you can dive deeper what's going on.

Comment: @Eldar There's no error caught. Right in `request.GetResponse()`, it just hangs, and, forever, won't go on the next statement.

Comment: What happens when you request the url manually with Postman like tools.

Comment: @Eldar I'll try it now

Comment: @Eldar  Well, no response as well..  -  perhaps it's the problem with the website.

Comment: Yeap probably, this kind of situations makes it necessary to trust your own code.

Comment: @Eldar Yes I tried another website and this code works well :>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not your problem i have checked it right now and the api is down

you can also check

https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/api.ipwarner.com.html

i signed up the site and tested it my self the api site is down

contact there support

Comment: let us know when this site is up then we can check again

Answer (score 1):

Please set time out and Try. Now, You will get the error message. Work on the error.

```
private static string Get(string uri)
 {
   string returnStr  = trsing.Empty;
  try
   {    
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Timeout=10;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream ?? throw new 
    InvalidOperationException());
    returnStr  = reader.ReadToEnd();
 }
 catch( Exception ex)
 {
  Debug.Writeline( ex.ToString());
 }

 return returnStr  ;
}
```